# Merge specific sheets by adding the sheet name as the first column

Tags: vba, excel

I have quite a number of sheets whose names end in **_A** or **_B**.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I would like to merge all sheets ending in  **_A** or **_B** under one another. They have the same number of columns, but different number of rows. However, when merging, I want the sheetname to be repeated all the way down the last row of that sheet in the merged sheet. Result:
[image]

I want the results to be saved in the same workbook but in a sheet called "merged".

[here is the example sheet if you would like to work on](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B73smSNUQ01-OWxNOFFNWDBucjg/view?usp=sharing).

**what I have tried:**

```
Sub Merge_into_One()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TargetRow As Long

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    TargetRow = 1
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        With ws
            If .Name Like "*" & strSearch & "_A" Or _
              .Name Like "*" & strSearch & "_B" Then
                .Range("A1:C99").Copy
                With Worksheets("Merged").Cells(TargetRow, 1)
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                    End With
                TargetRow = TargetRow + 99
            End If
        End With
    Next ws

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

But here, i am taking 99 rows, supposing that my rows will not exceed this number. However, I want to take exactly the same number of rows that appear in each sheet, not more not less. And here I cannot put the name of the sheet in the first column and repeat it until the last hit of the same sheet.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @DavidGM I updated my answer and what I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested.       EDIT: Oops I forgot a few things it seems.

```
dim RowsToMerge as integer
dim RowsPresent
dim RangeToMerge as range

For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
      If Instr(Worksheets(i).Name, "ABC") <> 0 Then
            Set ws = Worksheets(i)
            RowsToMerge = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            RowsPresent = Sheets("Merged").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set RangeToMerge = ws.Range("A1:C" & RowsToMerge)
            ws.RangeToMerge.Copy destination:=Worksheets("Merged").Range("B" & RowsPresent + 1)
            Worksheets("Merged").Range("A" & RowsPresent + 1) = ws.Name

      End If
Next
```

Comment: Actually the sheetnames ONLY have _A or _B in common, and not ABC. Some sheetnames are CGT, RTR, ERF, any name. But they all end in _A or _B .

Comment: Right now it will only copy the name of the worksheet at the first entry of that worksheet insetad of at the start of every row like you wanted. I have to go, don,t have time to complete it, but I think you should have a good start!

Comment: Then change "ABC" to "_"

Comment: actually i tried to test your answer, but there is an error. Could you please test it and tell me the correct version.

Comment: Can you try to debug and tell me what the error is and where? I cannot test it, i am at work now.

Comment: this line bugs: **ws.RangeToMerge.Copy destination:=Worksheets("Merged").Range("B" & RowsPresent + 1)**
by the way, another point: I want your code to look for sheets ending in **_A** or **_B**.

Comment: For the second part: Just replace the ABC part with this - If Instr(Worksheets(i).Name, "_A") <> 0 Or Instr(Worksheets(i).Name, "_B") <> 0 Then. I'm not sure what to do about the copying without testing it myself. But the range to copy should be successfullly stored in RangeToMerge, you can probably figure out how to properly use the .Copy with a quick search on google. Cheers

Comment: the second part is OK now. However, the rest is a bit unstable! I am trying to find the way around it. Please let me know as soon as you can. At the same time I am trying myself and if I come up with a fix, I will post it and accept your answer.

Comment: If I were you I would test it with .Select inseatd of copy/paste. Comment out some code and have it select the range that needs to be copied first (is it ok?) and then try to select the place it will paste from. If both are OK there is probably a mistake in the way I use it. You could test it in a new workbook, just copy and pasting ranges where you want and when you figure it out by itself it should be easy to fix.

Comment: I tried, but since I am a newbie. I cannot make it all by myself. I need your help or community's help. Please let me know when you test it. thanks

Comment: i am still waiting for you help please.

Comment: I tested the copy function and it works very well. That means it could be 2 things: either the range being copied has a problem, or the area we are sending it to has a problem. Look at where the 'destination' cell is by writing: msgbox(Worksheets("Merged").Range("B" & RowsPresent + 1))  just before "end if". Is the address being written the first cell in a blank row of the 'merged' sheet, column B? It should be. If it is, add: msgbox(rangetomerge.address) just after. Is the range written the one you want?